# add multiple views in scrollview

Tags: objective-c, view, subview, addsubview

I have a ScrollView and it will be filled with lots of views.

My views have a background and will receive a dynamic amount of buttons.

I need to add these views on my ScrollView.

Each view will be placed below the previous. My views have 1024 x 197

Hoe do I do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**MORE DETAILS**

I have created the view (the one I need repeated) on Interface Builder

```
@interface PortalBookViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *prateleira;
    UIScrollView *ScrollView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *prateleira;

@end
```

I have linked that View(Interface Builder) with *prateleira

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                prateleira = [prateleira initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 197)];
                [ScrollView addSubview:prateleira];
                [prateleira release];
                break;
            case 1:
                prateleira = [prateleira initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 198, 1024, 197)];
                [ScrollView addSubview:prateleira];
                [prateleira release];
                break;
            case 2:
                prateleira = [prateleira initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 384, 1024, 197)];
                [ScrollView addSubview:prateleira];
                [prateleira release];
                break;
                break;
            case 3:
                prateleira = [prateleira initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 582, 1024, 197)];
                [ScrollView addSubview:prateleira];
                [prateleira release];
                break;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    [ScrollView release];


}
```

**MODE DETAILS**

If I do that: `[self.ScrollView addSubview:prateleira];` it will show me this:

[image]

I think the problem is on setting the view position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to create a uiview object like:

```
UIView * shelf_view (NSInteger x, NSInteger y) {

    UIView *shelf = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 1024, 197)];
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelf.png"]];
    [shelf addSubview:background];
    return shelf;

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                [ScrollView addSubview: shelf_view(0, 0)];
                break;
            case 1:
                [ScrollView addSubview: shelf_view(0, 197)];
                break;
            case 2:
                [ScrollView addSubview: shelf_view(0, 512)];
                break;
            case 3:
                [ScrollView addSubview: shelf_view(0, 777)];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ScrollView release];


}
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you simple add those as usual like so:

[self.myScroller addSubview:mytextview];

after you've set the textviews frame. or do you mean something else?

you'd have to calculate the frame in your loop, so each view is added below the next one, if it's that what you mean...

best,
marcus

Comment: Thanks Marcus but how do I change the position the view will be displayed on the ScrollView? Otherwise, it will be on top of the previous

Comment: if it would be a textview, you set the frame like so: UITextView *allocTextpart1 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 260.0)]; the next one be like so: UITextView *allocTextpart1 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 520.0)]; so the top y-value of frame #2 is at the bottom y-value of #1

Comment: It is not a UITextView, its a UIView and inside that View, I have some buttons and images...I'll try your code...

Comment: taht doesn't matter in that case, as the buttons aswell as the view as UIView's decendants, so they all got a frame-property with (x,y,width,height). That you must calculate and set 8)

Comment: Your code didn't work...even setting the values that I need to give the correct position to be placed.

Comment: if you nest you buttons inside a view and that view inside your scroller, you have to position the buttons inside the view and position the view inside the scroller aswell..

Comment: Yeah...I know that but by now, I'm just trying to add those views, they have a background, so I know they were added correctly but none is shown.

Comment: Yep...if I try to add it like this: [ScrollView addSubview:prateleira]; outside the for() it works

Comment: try self.Scrollview in your loop, might be scope-related

Comment: can you add the buttons directly and correctly positioned into your scrollview?

Comment: I can do that with Interface Builder, is that what you mean?

Comment: nope, you should do that programmatically. add the (synthesized) scrollview like so:    UIScrollView *allocScollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 300.0, 370.0)];  [allocScollview release];
 allocScollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 600);
 allocScollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 allocScollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 self.Scrollview = allocScollview;

Comment: But the problem is when I try to set the view position and add it to the scrollview

Comment: you could try and change the UIView to an UIViewController. Otherwise, you might send me your project, so I could look into at tomorrow, if you'd like.

Comment: Marcus, I'm gonna try to create a Object and instantiate it every time I need it...I'll try that and return with the results ;) thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: Do so and have phun. IMHO, one should avoid IB in most cases as it obfuscates more than it helps. As sad before, if you like, send me your project. Best regards, Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Use addSubview:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:myNewView];
```

Comment: I know that, but how to set multiple views and one below the previous?